# What does Promise chain order matter when Promise is rejected?

Tags: javascript

When a `Promise` is rejected, and `.then()` comes after `.catch()`, the rejection is caught, but the following then still runs (see `then` example below).

However, when a `Promise` is resolved, and `.then()` comes before `.catch()`, the rejection is caught, and `.then()` is never called.

Why do these two cases behave differently, and what is a situation in which it would be useful to have a `.then()` call after a rejection was caught?

```
var then = Promise.reject()
    .catch(() => 'catch')
    .then(() => document.getElementById('then').innerHTML = 'then');

var noThen = Promise.reject()
    .then(() => document.getElementById('noThen').innerHTML = 'then')
  .catch((err) => 'catch');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmyj61dd/

EDIT:

An interesting related example that illustrates how dependent `.then()` is on the parameters of the function it is passed:

```
var then = Promise.reject()
  .then((undefined, err) => 'catch')
  .then((asdf) => document.getElementById('then').innerHTML = 'then');

var noThen = Promise.reject()
  .then((asdf) => document.getElementById('noThen').innerHTML = 'then')
  .then((undefined, err) => 'catch');
```

Only the `(undefined, err) => 'catch'` functions get called here in both cases.

https://jsfiddle.net/ro0cv1p1/2/

Comment: But it makes logical sense, no?

Comment: `then` after a `catch` is like doing a `finally`   So acts similar to a Javascript finally -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: depends how you write your .then. The first argument to the callback is run when the promise is fulfilled, the second (optional) argument runs when the promise is rejected. catch and then are not opposites. You could use the second argument to "then" instead of a separate "catch", if you wanted. Different ways to write the same thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch explain it

Comment: @Keith If that's the case, then why does this behave differently? jsfiddle.net/ro0cv1p1/2

Comment: @maxhud  Not sure what you fiddle is proving, your not using catch in your fiddle.  So `then` after `catch` = `finally` is still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's analogous to a traditional `try..catch`:

```
try {
    foo();
    bar();
} catch (e) {
    baz();
}
```

This is different from:

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (e) {
    baz();
}

bar();
```

The practical application is simple to explain: *try something (start a promise), if it fails produce some default value instead, then continue with the asynchronous chain.* For instance:

```
fetch('http://example.com')
    .then(result => result.somevalue)
    .catch(e => 'default value')
    .then(value => alert(value));
```

This either displays `somevalue` fetched from `example.com` or the `default value`.

Answer (score 1):

No `then` (actually no first callback in `then`, because second callback is indeed alternative for catch) will be called until you "catch rejection" in the chain and return "positive" value - **`catch` function should return anything that's not unresolved Promise and should not throw and Error**  to "fix" Promise in the chain.
If the `catch` will return such value next `then` will be called, it will also get return value of the `catch` as a param.
And again, if `then` is being called and throws an Error or returns rejected Promise, next `then` in chain won't be called until "catching the rejection".

E.g.

```
let resolvedPromiseAfterAll = Promise.reject()
    .then(() => 'then') // <-not called
    .catch(e => { console.log(e); throw e; }) // <- only error log
    .then(() => 'then 2') // <- still not called because previous catch didn't resolve the promise
    .catch(e => 'catched') // <- return 'catched' that is equiv to Promise.resolve('catched')
    .then(val => { console.log('then 2', val); return 'ok'; }) // <-- this promise should finally be called because previous catch didn't throw Error or returned rejected Promise. We also get 'catch' as first param in then callback so the console.log is 'then 2 catched'.
```

This is how Promise chain works - you can get from rejected Promise to resolved by catching rejection reason and returning something that's not error, and you can 'break' resolved Promise by returning rejected Promise or throwing an Error in attached `then`.

It's quite powerful feature, in your implementation you decide what to do on rejection, so if you'll do something like this (no `catch`es):
`somePromise.then().then().then()` 
means you don't want to call any of following `then` callbacks if something goes wrong on any stage.
But if you want to handle Promise rejection on some `then`, you add `catch` after this `then`.

It's similar to try/catch - some part of code in try block won't be called if exception was thrown in one of previous lines in this block.

Btw, fixed your fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ro0cv1p1/3/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle update. I didn't see that until just now